# Does OCMockito reset invocation count after a verify() call?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmockito

Here is the pseudocode of my unit test:

```
int invocationCount
given(mock).willDo {
    invocationCount++
    return value
}
doSomeProcessing()
verify(mock)
doSomeMoreProcessing()
verifyCount(mock, 2)
```

At this point, `invocationCount == 2`, as expected. However, `verifyCount` fails, saying it was only called once. In addition, if I exclude the first `verify` call, the test passes as expected. It might be relevant to note that each `verify` call is capturing a new argument for assertion later.

My question is this: when the first `verify()` is called, is the mock's invocation count reset?  If this is not the case, what could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, verification only counts the matches since the last verification.

Further discussion can be found here: https://github.com/jonreid/OCMockito/issues/116